# Почему нестабильно воспроизводится видео?

Tags: javascript, html

Воспроизводится при наведении только после того как кликнуть где нибудь на экране.

```
<video id="myVideo" poster="images/slide1.jpg">
             <source src="videos/video1.mp4">
   <a href="videos/video1.mp4">Скачайте видео</a>.
  </video>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');

vid.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  vid.play();
});

vid.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  vid.pause();
});
}
</script>
```

Ошибка в консоли: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first;

Comment: Ну вот вы и ответ на ваш вопрос сами написали только что. Какое слово вам непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: Есть какое-нибудь решение?

Comment: Нет, поведение абсолютно правильное, именно так и было задумано разработчиками браузеров